# Java - Read a string of numbers into columns by rows

Tags: java, android, ondraw

I have a grid in this form:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0
```

and I will be receiving it in a string form:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

this is just an example of a 5 by 5 grid. But in actual, I have 20 columns by 15 rows. The values in the grid will not be only in zeroes.

However, I would like to know how to read a string of numbers like this into columns by rows. I am depending on this string to check the grid with colours in android's GUI using onDraw method. Where my method reads in column by row.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: After every 20 cols you change the row? Is that what you want? :)

Comment: @LittleChild yup. that's right.

Comment: @Durandal I would like to know how to implement the logic so that I could display them correctly on the grid view in the onDraw method

Comment: @Winona Like LittleChild said. Our next question is *What have you tried* :) And we don't take a *nothing* as incentive to answer anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for giving me the opportunity to learn and think on my own. Of course, thank you @xgeorgekx for the codes that gave me my own idea of solving my own problem using your codes as reference. I did it in this way though, I know it is not fully optimised. I welcome any suggestions!

Firstly, I get rid of all the spaces in the string. then using numColumns as 15 and numRows as 20, i used 2 loops and stored the values of the string parsed to int as i needed the element of the array as the cellType so as to set the colour.

```
String spaceFilter = map.replaceAll(" ", "");       
    for (int i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
            if (spaceFilter.length() != 0) {
                cellType[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(spaceFilter.substring(0,1));
                spaceFilter = spaceFilter.substring(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Haven't tested it. But i think you need something like that. Split the input and every 20 numbers create a new `array`

```
String input = //put the input here

String[] inputSplitted = input.split(" "); //create array that holds all values.


int colSize = 20;

for(int i = 0; i < inputSplitted.length; i ++){
    String[] row = new String[20]; //create array to hold a row
    for(int j = i; j < i + row.length; j++) 
        row[j-i] = inputSplitted[j]; //add ekements the row

    // do something with row

    i += row.length; //increase i by row length so you add row.length + 1 index to the next row
}
```

Note that every row now is a `String[]`. If you want to use the elements of the array as `int`s you have to do `Integer.parseInt(row[i]);` etc.

Hope this helps.

If you want to stored the values in a 2d `array` please comment below and i will update my answer.

Comment: Did you not read the comments? You've given Op the answer, now they have no incentive to try and learn. All that happens is the Op ends up being another automaton that can't think for itself.

Comment: The answer is pretty commented so the OP can perfectly understand what's going on and not just copy paste the code. Also the OP is not a 1rep user. Quite obvious he has some knowledge and can see the logic behind the code.

Comment: Commenting does not stop copy and paste. And If the Op truly has some knowledge then why can't they think how to approach this trivial problem?